# Ltac : optional arguments tactic

Tags: coq, variadic, ltac

I want to make a Ltac tactic in coq which would take either 1 or 3 arguments. I have read about `ltac_No_arg` in the [`LibTactics`](http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/ssphs/LibTactics.html) module but if I understood it correctly I would have to invoke my tactic with :

```
Coq < mytactic arg_1 ltac_no_arg ltac_no_arg.
```

which is not very convenient.

Is there any way to get a result like this ? :

```
Coq < mytactic arg_1.

Coq < mytactic arg_1 arg_2 arg_3.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use the [`Tactic Notation`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html#coq:cmd.tactic-notation) mechanism to try to solve your issue because it can handle variadic arguments.

Let's reuse `ltac_No_arg` and define a dummy tactic `mytactic` for the purposes of demonstration

```
Inductive ltac_No_arg : Set :=
  | ltac_no_arg : ltac_No_arg.

Ltac mytactic x y z :=
  match type of y with
  | ltac_No_arg => idtac "x =" x  (* a bunch of cases omitted *)
  | _ => idtac "x =" x "; y =" y "; z =" z
  end.
```

Now let's define the aforementioned tactic notations:

```
Tactic Notation "mytactic_notation" constr(x) :=
  mytactic x ltac_no_arg ltac_no_arg.
Tactic Notation "mytactic_notation" constr(x) constr(y) constr(z) :=
  mytactic x y z.
```

Tests:

```
Goal True.
  mytactic_notation 1.
  mytactic_notation 1 2 3.
Abort.
```

Comment: What is `constr(x)`? `x` in Vernacular?

Comment: It specifies the type of an argument for `Tactic Notation`. Here, `constr(x)` means we parse and interpret `x` as a term, not an identifier, integer and so on.

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual003.html#term)? The definition is as broad as it gets (e.g. types and sorts are proper subclasses of terms, `qualid` is a term, defined as identifier, etc.)

Comment: No, I meant [this section](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual014.html#sec578).

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Fixed, thanks. But the docs are being ported to Sphinx now, so not for long I guess.