# Ltac: optional variable name

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ltac

I would like to write a tactic with an optional variable name. The original tactic looks like this:

```
Require Import Classical.

Ltac save := 
  let H := fresh in
  apply NNPP;
  intro H;
  apply H.
```

I would like to give the user an opportunity to choose the name he wants and use it like: `save a` for example.

I wrote a variation using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840624/ltac-optional-arguments-tactic):

```
Require Import Classical.

Inductive ltac_No_arg : Set :=
  | ltac_no_arg : ltac_No_arg.

Ltac savetactic h := 
  match type of h with
    | ltac_No_arg => let H := fresh in
      apply NNPP;
      intro H;
      apply H
    | _ => apply NNPP;
      intro h;
      apply h
  end.

Tactic Notation "save" := savetactic ltac_no_arg.
Tactic Notation "save" ident(x) := savetactic x.
```

However this proof fails on `save h`:

```
Lemma te (A B : Prop) : A \/ ~A.
Proof.
save h.
right.
intro a.
apply h.
left.
exact a.
Qed.
```

The error message:

```
In nested Ltac calls to "save (ident)", "savetactic" and "h", last term evaluation failed.
In nested Ltac calls to "save (ident)", "savetactic" and "h", last term evaluation failed.
Variable h should be bound to a term but is bound to a ident.
```

I guess I must make sure that `h` is fresh, but I am unsure on how to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that that solution involved an argument that was a term (a `constr`), whereas you have a name (an `ident`ifier). However, you can solve your problem more simply with a tactic notation that provides a fresh identifier.

```
Require Import Classical_Prop.

Ltac savetactic h := 
     apply NNPP;
      intro h;
      apply h.

Tactic Notation "save" := let H := fresh in savetactic H.
Tactic Notation "save" ident(x) := savetactic x.

Lemma te (A B : Prop) : A \/ ~A.
Proof.
  save h.
  right.
  intro a.
  apply h.
  left.
  exact a.
Qed.
```

The one problem with this solution is that it calls `fresh` before running `savetactic` at all, which won't work if you wanted that `h` to be fresh after doing some other work inside `savetactic`. The only difference this would make is in the auto-generated names, though, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your last paragraph, do you mean if I would use a tactic that creates variables like intro before using h?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You might introduce variables with `intro` or `intros`, or you might use `assert` or `pose proof`.

Comment: And what did involve my argument to be a constr? Because of match with?

Comment: I think it's actually `type of h`, which doesn't make sense when `h` is an identifier and so you get a dynamic type error.